# Given 2 xyz and timestamp; derive speed

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using the following code to get the distance of two xyz coordinates.

```
function dist(x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1){
  deltaX = x1 - x0;
  deltaY = y1 - y0;
  deltaZ = z1 - z0;
  distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ);
  return distance;
}
```

For given two coordinates.

```
arr1 = [1524519105.309092, 575131.076859, 4141688.619666, -14.086608]
arr2 = [1524519105.310092, 575131.082497, 4141688.628375, -14.086852]
```

Where index 0 represents timestamp; and following 3 numbers represent xyz.
My goal is to compare these 2 coordinates and derive speed. Here's what I have so far:

```
let x2 = arr2[1] // Array 2 x
let y2 = arr2[2] // Array 2 y
let z2 = arr2[3] // Array 2 z
let x1 = arr1[1] // Array 1 x
let y1 = arr1[2] // Array 1 y
let z1 = arr1[3] // Array 1 z
var c = dist(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2)
var time_difference = arr1[0] - arr2[0] // time difference 
var speed = Math.round(c / time_difference);
```

The  does not give me the right speed; there are times I get -0, which makes me believe I'm doing something wrong in time difference.
My overall goal is to get speed in meters per second.

Comment: time_difference in your example is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with Three.js, use its capabilities.

```js
var arr1 = [1524519105.309092, 575131.076859, 4141688.619666, -14.086608]
var arr2 = [1524519105.310092, 575131.082497, 4141688.628375, -14.086852]

var vec1 = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(arr1, 1);
var vec2 = new THREE.Vector3().fromArray(arr2, 1);

var timeDiff = arr2[0] - arr1[0]; // next minus current

var speed = vec2.sub(vec1).divideScalar(timeDiff).length(); // next minus current divided by time difference

console.log({speed});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sweet! Is the output in meters per second or mph?

Comment: @babadahal You're welcome :) It is in units you're using in elements of arrays

Answer (score 0):

> `var time_difference = arr1[0] - arr2[0]`

Your `arr1[0]` timestamp comes before (is smaller than) the `arr2[0]` timestamp. So, in this case, `arr1[0] - arr2[0]` will be negative. If you always want a positive `speed` no matter what the `arr`s are, use `Math.abs` on the result first:

```js
function dist(x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1){
  deltaX = x1 - x0;
  deltaY = y1 - y0;
  deltaZ = z1 - z0;
  distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ);
  return distance;
}


arr1 = [1524519105.309092, 575131.076859, 4141688.619666, -14.086608]
arr2 = [1524519105.310092, 575131.082497, 4141688.628375, -14.086852]

let x2 = arr2[1] // Array 2 x
let y2 = arr2[2] // Array 2 y
let z2 = arr2[3] // Array 2 z
let x1 = arr1[1] // Array 1 x
let y1 = arr1[2] // Array 2 y
let z1 = arr1[3] // Array 3 z
var c = dist(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2)
var time_difference = Math.abs(arr1[0] - arr2[0]);
var speed = Math.round(c / time_difference);
console.log(speed);
```

Comment: Is speed in meters per second?

Comment: It's your data, I have no idea what the units you're using are - you didn't specify in the question. (though the timestamp looks to be in seconds since the epoch)

Comment: Just to confirm, I'm not sure what format the time stamp is either. However for the given time stamp the implementation you purposed should work to derive speed, right?

Comment: Yes, if you always want `speed` to come out positive or `0`, call `Math.abs` on the `time_difference`.

Comment: Perfect, then I'll mark this question as completed. Thanks for your time.